# How to link a DLL in a Delphi package?

Tags: delphi, dll, hyperlink, package, external

I'm creating a Delphi package using OpenGL and the GLEW extension. I downloaded GLEW from the official website. That was a painful way to make it usable with Embarcadero, but I finally succeeded. At this point, I'm able to compile and use GLEW in any C++ Builder or Delphi application project.

However, I experiment difficulties to use GLEW in my Delphi package. As GLEW is a DLL, I declare the external functions that I need as in the following example:

```
procedure glBindVertexArray(glArray: GLuint); external 'glew32.dll' name '__glewBindVertexArray';
```

This works well when I compile an application project, so I'm sure that the declaration is correct. I can compile and link my package without problems. However, when I try to use it in a demo project, I receive the following link error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__glewBindVertexArray' referenced from C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\15.0\DCP\QRMODELS.LIB|TQRMD2_OpenGL
```

So my GLEW functions are not found by the linker. The problem is that I don't know how to link an external DLL into a Delphi package. When I try to add the DLL in the "Requires" section, my package can no more be compiled and I receive the following error:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] QRModels.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'glew32' not found
```

I also tried to add glew32.lib in my package, and tried to link GLEW in my target project, but without success.

So, what is the correct way to link an external standard DLL, that isn't a .dcp, in Embarcadero Delphi packages? I remember you that I can use this DLL without problems in any Delphi application project, and I own the corresponding .lib too, that is already converted to be used with Embarcadero compiler.

Regards

**NOTE**: As suggested in the comment posted by David Heffernan, I tried to create a small package that includes an external function to the user32.dll. This worked well. I also tried to include one of my GLEW external function. Now the issue is different: the package links and builds well, and the target project too. But when the exe runs, I get an error message saying that glew32.dll is missing on my computer. So my issue is basically a bad installation of the GLEW library. However, all my other projects using GLEW works well, including those I create with other compilers, as e.g. Code::Blocks.

I also compared my package options, and the only thing that is different is that the package I create is divided in 2 projects, one for the design time and one for the runtime. I already created such other packages without problems, but I never tried to include external DLL in them.

Here is my test unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses OpenGL;

function MessageBeep(uType: Cardinal): LongBool; stdcall; external 'user32';
procedure glBindVertexArray(glArray: GLuint); stdcall; external 'glew32.dll' name '__glewBindVertexArray';

type
    TTest = class(TObject)
        public
            procedure TestBeep; virtual;
            procedure TestGlew; virtual;
    end;

implementation
procedure TTest.TestBeep;
begin
    MessageBeep($40);
end;

procedure TTest.TestGlew;
begin
    glBindVertexArray(0);
end;

end.
```

Regards

Comment: Can you show a minimal reproduction. Linking to DLLs is fine from packages. You do need to stop trying to use .lib files though.

Comment: However I only declare the external functions as shown above, then I use them as any other functions. In my target project, I experiment no problems to build and use packaged objects that not contains calling to these external functions. So, what kind of material will be useful to reproduce here?

Comment: A complete MCVE will help, because what you are trying to do should just work. As it stands, we are left trying to guess exactly how you did this, and attempt to reproduce what should work. Rather than using OpenGL, can you make a repro with a simple Win32 function. Like this one: `function MessageBeep(uType: Cardinal): LongBool; stdcall; external 'user32';`

Comment: Also, this is how you track down and isolate such issues. Remove everything that is extraneous to the problem until there is so little left that the problem becomes obvious. This really is debugging 101.

Comment: Ok, I tried to create a simple package containing only one of the GLEW functions. I needed to copy glew32.dll into the RAD studio bin folder, but finally I could compile my package. In a target project, I tried to create a TTest object, and to call the TestGlew function. I could not link my target projet, same error as above. I tried to copy my glew32.dll near the target project exe file, in the RAD studio DCP or BPL folders, in windows system32 and syswow64, and in many other folders, nothing to do. So, where should I copy my DLL to make it visible by RAD studio? (Used code is shown above)

Comment: RAD Studio doesn't need to see a DLL file in order to compile code that links against it. Unfortunately you've now destroyed your system by copying your DLL everywhere. You need to undo that. You really must stop modifying system folders. Try to stop doing that.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, and now I reverted all my changes. I cleaned all the copies of glew32.dll that I previously manually copied. However, my target project still cannot link to it. Despite all my efforts, the result is always the same: [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__glewBindVertexArray' referenced from C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\15.0\DCP\PACKAGE1.LIB|Unit1, even with the above posted code. Sorry, I don't understand what is wrong here...

Comment: Is it better to load the DLL in runtime, using the LoadLibrary() function?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong either. You should be able to provide an MCVE like I said. And no, it's better to link implicitly as you are attempting, in general.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible for the linker to find 'glew32.dll' (is it in the search path or in the working path of the Debugger)?

maybe this can help you

http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Link_object_file_(Delphi)

https://hub.packtpub.com/implementing-c-libraries-in-delphi-for-hpc-tutorial/

The last article is part of Delphi High Performance from Packt (a very good book on Delphi)

By the way, if you want to include a .lib file in Delphi, it is not enough to just add the .lib file to the project. You have to include the .lib file with {$ L 'LibName.lib'}

here's an Embarcadero Link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Link_object_file_(Delphi)

You just have to make sure that your .lib file is in the correct format e.g. OMF, COFF, ELF coz Visual Studio uses COFF, Delphi OMF and C++ Builder ELF

Delphi 64-Bit Windows Compiler http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/DCC64

Delphi 32-Bit Windows Compiler http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/DCC32

C++ Builder 64-Bit Windows Compiler http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/BCC64

if your .lib file is not in the correct format, you can use the following open source project to convert it
https://github.com/gitGNU/objconv